# Why is this PHP variable not incrementing per request?

Tags: php

In the response `$numOfEmployees` is always the same every time I submit a new form. What am I doing wrong here? I attempted to save it to the session every time but still it's not working. I'm new to PHP and so far not the biggest fan...

```
<?php

class Employee{

    private $fn;
    private $ln;
    private $dpt;
    private $ID;

    public function setVars($fna, $lna, $dpta, $numOfEmployeesa){
        $this-> fn = $fna;
        $this -> ln = $lna;
        $this -> dpt = $dpta;
        $this -> ID = $numOfEmployeesa;
    }

}
if(isset($_SESSION['numOfEmployees'])){
    //get it
    $numOfEmployees = $_SESSION['numOfEmployees'];
} else {
    //set a default value if not isset
    $numOfEmployees = 0;
}
if(isset($_SESSION['employeeArray'])){
    //get it
    $employeeArray = $_SESSION['employeeArray'];
} else {
    //set a default value if not isset
    $employeeArray = array();
}

$employee = new Employee();
$fn = $_POST['firstname'];
$ln = $_POST['lastname'];
$dpt = $_POST['department'];

$employee -> setVars($fn, $ln, $dpt, $numOfEmployees);

$numOfEmployees++;

echo "First Name: " . $fn . "\nLast Name: " . $ln . "\nDepartment: " . $dpt . "\nID: " . sprintf('%08d', $numOfEmployees) . "\nNumber of employees: " . $numOfEmployees;

$employeeArray[] = $employee;

$_SESSION['employeeArray'] = $employeeArray;
$_SESSION['numOfEmployees'] = $numOfEmployees;

?>
```

Comment: you need to replace `$somevalue = ` with `$numOfEmployees =` and `$employeeArray =` in your two if statements

Comment: To use session you need to call `session_start`

Comment: thanks I fixed the variables still not working

Comment: got it @lessan was right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `session_start()` at the begining of your file

Comment: do i put that at the top of the file but inside the <?php tag?

Comment: thanks that was what did it! I'll mark your answer as correct when it lets me.